# How to get team members and owners from microsoft teams?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I need to get the list of members and owners from a team in Microsoft Teams. So far I've been doing it using `GET /groups/{id}/owners` method with Graph API. But to use it, it requires Group.Read.All permission which needs an admin consent.
Is there any other way to get team owners that don't require the use of an admin only permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. No matter which type of permission (application permission or delegated permission) you are using, `Group.Read.All` is necessary.

And both application permission and delegated permission are requiring admin consent. There is no other way to bypass admin consent.

See details from [List owners Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

[image]